# C#, Access to different class members thread safety

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Is writing to different class members thread safe in C#? I Mean having X threads, each one read/write only from one class member/ property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Thread1WokringHere = null;
    public string Thread2WorkingHere { get; set;}
}
```

The MyClass instance's reference is protected by a lock, I'm asking If I need a finer lock.

Comment: `The MyClass instance's reference is protected by a lock, I'm asking If I need a finer lock.` What exatly is a "finer" lock?

Comment: Using a mutex for each member. I mean "Finer grain"

Comment: If each member is only ever accessed by a single thread, you don't need any lock at all.

Comment: please post the consumer code as well.. Ideally you "cannot" guarantee that a thread will access a single property ever.. Thread safety is required to ensure if multiple threads try, then the access is safe.. Here you are *assuming*, as you are owning the code, and assumptions aren't safe

Comment: Ok the question should be, "Are there any race conditions if I guarantee that each thread can access / set /read /write" only  1 property?